# switchClass, remove all classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jquery ui switchClass method. Right now it works as such:

```
$("#top_section").switchClass( "top_section", "pt_figures", 300);
```

What I'd like to change it to is instead of removing only `top_section`, I'd like to remove all classes then add `pt_figures`.

it works here:

```
$("#close_icon").click(function() {
$("#top_section").removeClass();
$("#top_section").addClass( "top_section", 300);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#images').empty();
}, 350);

});
```

but not here:

```
$("#pt_figures").click(function() {


$('#images').empty();

$('#images').css({
  paddingLeft: 150,
  paddingRight: 0
});
$('#controls').css({
  width:700,
  marginLeft:150
});
$('#info').css({
  width:660,
  marginLeft:150
});

var id = $(this).attr('id');

$("#info_header").load(id +"_header.txt");
$("#content_1").load(id +"_1.txt");
$("#content_2").load(id +"_2.txt");
$("#content_3").load(id +"_3.txt");


$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figures_doc.jpg" }).appendTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_front.png" }).appendTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_back.jpg" }).appendTo("#images");

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: 0
}, 300);



$("#top_section").removeClass();
$("#top_section").addClass( "pt_figures", 300);


});
```

Comment: $("#top_section").removeClass();
  $("#top_section").addClass( "pt_figures", 300);

Comment: but this doesn't animate, it just immediately moves to the new class attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing all classes, add the class you want to switch out, and switch it with the class you want in:

```
    $(#top_section).removeClass();
    $(#top_section).addClass('top_section');
    $(#top_section).switchClass('top_section', 'pt_figures', 300);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eybxf/)

Comment: i added more above, it works with the first example, but not with the second, I'm not sure why.  Second one there is no animation, just instantly happens, first one animates.

Comment: Fyi, with your code `$("#top_section").removeClass(); 
$("#top_section").addClass( "pt_figures", 300);`, it will do the animation from having no class. With my code, it will do the animation from the `top_section` class, which seemed like what you wanted. If the first example works but not the second, are you sure the code at the bottom is being reached, and that `pt_figures` is defined?